# Web Form crashing with more than 1 timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

**Issue**
I have a asp.net webForm that has several timers. When all the timers are active and running, the webform will "stop" running at exactly 82 seconds. There is no crash redirect or error, but if I look at the Dev Console it shows lots of 500 errors (screen shot below).
**Other Information**
The application has a total of 13 timers. 1 timer is just a clock, and ticks every 1 second (this is how I can see exactly when the page stops). The other 12 timers are panels that pull information on each tick. The ticks of these panels ranges from 5 minutes to 15 minutes.
When debugging/running the application from Visual Studios, it never stops or crashes, its when I publish it to an IIS Webserver that is has the problem.
I have removed all timers except the clock, and that fixes the issue, so it only seems to happen when there is more than 1 timer.
**Single Timer Code**

```
 <asp:Timer runat="server" id="clockTimer" interval="1000" ontick="clockTimer_Tick" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel2" updatemode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="clockTimer" eventname="Tick" />
        </Triggers>

protected void clockTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clockLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```

**Example of more than 1 timer code**

```
     <asp:Timer runat="server" id="clockTimer" interval="1000" ontick="clockTimer_Tick" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel2" updatemode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="clockTimer" eventname="Tick" />
        </Triggers>

protected void clockTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clockLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

<asp:Timer runat="server" id="priTimer" interval="300000" ontick="priTimer_Tick" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="priTimer" eventname="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate> 
            <div class="card border-light mb-3">
             <div class="card-header" style="font-size: 1vw; background-color:grey; color:white;" id="priHead">Primary <asp:Label ID="priBadge" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
             <asp:ListBox ID="priList" runat="server" style="font-size: 1vw; OVERFLOW:auto; width:100%"></asp:ListBox>
             <div class="card-footer" style="font-size: .25vw; background-color:grey; color:white; max-height:30px;" id="priFoot"><asp:Label ID="priLastfire" runat="server" class="font-italic; text-light;" style="font-size: .5vw;" Text=""></asp:Label></div>
            </div>
         </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void priTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        priList.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            string[] priRead = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Data_Scripts\Primary\priDown.txt");
            foreach (string line in priRead)
            {
                priList.Items.Add(line);
            }
            priBadge.Text = priList.Items.Count.ToString();

        }

        catch

        {
            priList.Items.Add("Error pulling data");
            priBadge.Text = "NA";
        }
        DateTime nextFire = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(priTimer.Interval);
        priLastfire.Text = "Last Fire: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " ----- Next Fire: " + nextFire.ToShortTimeString();
        priColor();
    }
```

**Screenshot of the 500 error(s)**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance - I tried to add as much information and make it as clear as possible.

Comment: You need to figure out what the 500 server error is. Do you handle the Application_Error event? Log those errors anywhere?

Comment: @mason I do not, going to try and add that in now - I apologize, this is my first asp.net application.

Comment: Do you have to use Web Forms? That's really ancient technology, and it's pretty much a dead framework. You really should look into the various options in ASP.NET Core, such as MVC, Razor Pages, Blazor, or Web API with a SPA framework.

Comment: @mason I do not 'have' too, but prefer too because I am picking up where someone left off, and rather not do a full rewrite, however, I know that is the better option.

Comment: @dwb webforms is a well tested and proved technology, and we work with them and make wonderful thinks fast and easy... Get on EventViewer to see if its possible the log to locate the real error. Its maybe some kind of conflict with the data post, it maybe need some kind of synchronization using mutex or lock because on iis you may have more than one pool.